# calculate arbitrary points from a plane equation

Tags: geometry

I understand how one can calculate a plane equation (ax+by+cz=d) from three points but how can you go in reverse?

How can you calculate arbitrary points from a plane equation?

Comment: Do you mean tell whether or not a point lies in the plane? Just plug in its coordinates into the equation; if ax+by+cz does not equal d, then it does not lie in the plane, if it does equal d, then it does lie in the plane.

Comment: You can convert the plane to parameter-form 
$\vec{x} = \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{u} + \mu \vec{v} \quad \text{with } \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and pick arbitrary values for $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then compute the resulting $\vec{x}$ which is in the plane.

Comment: no, i mean how can I calculate a set of unknown points from ax+by+cz=d. the x, y, z intercepts are one way to approach it but I wanted to know if there was another way (a=b=0, solve for z, etc.)

Comment: how could I convert the plane eqtn(ax+by+cz=d) to parametric form. I am not familiar with this concept

Comment: Think of $\vec{a}$ as the base-point, then you have two vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ which are two "direction vectors" from this point which describe the whole plane. You can compute these from the three original points $A,B,C$ quite easily. Pick one as the base-point (e.g. $A$), then $\vec{u} = \vec{AB}$ and $\vec{v} = \vec{AC}$. Else, there are tons of questions here and material on the internet about this.

Comment: ok, the only values I have to start with are a, b,c, d coefficient from the plane equation. I don't have a base point

Comment: Possible related question/answer on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23474396/380384)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get three non-colinear points on a plane?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8388382/380384)

Answer (score 9):

From your comment I finally understood what you are looking for:

If you have a plane defined by $a x + b y + c z = d$ then you also have the following properties:

- Plane normal direction: 
  $$\hat{n} = \begin{pmatrix} 
    \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \\
    \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \\
    \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \end{pmatrix}$$
- Point on plane closest to the origin (position of plane)
  $$ \vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{a d}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \\
    \frac{b d}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \\
    \frac{c d}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \end{pmatrix} $$
- Distance of plane from the origin
  $$ r = \frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} $$
- Directions along the plane (not unit vectors), and perpendicular to $\hat{n}$.
  $$ \begin{align}
    \hat{e}_1 & = \begin{pmatrix}    c-b \\  a-c \\ b-a \end{pmatrix} &
    \hat{e}_2 & = \begin{pmatrix}  a (b+c)-b^2-c^2 \\ b (a+c) -a^2-c^2 \\ c (a+b)-a^2 - b^2  \end{pmatrix} \end{align} $$

You can verify that $\hat{e}_1 \cdot \hat{n} =0$, $\hat{e}_2 \cdot \hat{n}=0$ and $\hat{e}_1 \cdot \hat{e}_2 =0$, where $\cdot$ is the dot (inner) product.

Confirmation via GeoGebra

[image: pic]

<sub>NOTES: Please edit the equation to make it clear you are looking for the plane properties when given a plane in equation form.</sub>

Comment: This post would be a good approach except I do not know how to calculate the center point of the rectangle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769430/find-corners-of-rectangle-given-plane-equation-height-and-width

Comment: a normal vector and a point will give you a plane equation. im trying to go backwards from the plane equation to find a point at the center of the plane

Comment: perhaps, i should rephrase the question. how could I generate a rectangle (corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4) from the plane equation

Comment: From the information I in this answer use the two direction vectors to form a rectangle.

Comment: There were typos in the equations that I finally fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You pick arbitrarely two values $a,b$ for $x$ and $y$, you plug them in the equation, you solve it for $z$ and obtain a value $c$. The point $(a,b,c)$ is a point of your plane.

Comment: but how do I know the two arbitrary values for x and y are on the plane?

Comment: if your equation has an equation of the form $ax+bx+cx=d$ and $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, you can pick $x$ and $y$ as you wish they will be one the plane.